# Git - getting "WARNING: terminal is not fully functional" - how to fix it?

Tags: git, windows-7

I get that message (see title) when I type

```
$ git log
```

I tried many many ways proposed by StackOverflow members but it does not work for me.

Tried this:

```
    <Rclick>Computer, Properties, 
  [Advanced System Settings], [Advanced], [Environment Variables]
  Create a new System variable "TERM", value "msys"
```

And this:

```
created a .bashrc file in ~/ and typed this line in it: export TERM=msys
```

but to no avail.

Any other ways to fix it ??

Comment: Duplicate: [why does git diff on windows warn that the terminal is not fully functional](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949956/why-does-git-diff-on-windows-warn-that-the-terminal-is-not-fully-functional)

Comment: I saw that question with its green-checked answer. Tried it = added the this line 'export TERM=msys' to ~/.bashrc.  But it does not work

Comment: Are you running git from the `bash` terminal that it ships with, or via `cmd.exe`?

Comment: Did you restart bash or run `source ~/.bashrc` after modifying said file?

Answer (score 0):

ok now its working.
I rebooted my system so maybe that was what I had to do as a final step

Comment: You don't need to reboot the system.... closing the cmd prompt and re-opening a new one will work.